# Cannot get dropdown with text search to work in Angularjs using md-select

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angularjs and need some assistance please.
I am trying to get a simple dropdown with text search working, but the text search is not filtering the options in the dropdown.

The following .js code is used to get the data for the list:

```
var merchantRefDataList = localStorageService.get("merchantRefDataList");
for (i = 0; i < merchantRefDataList.length; i++) {
    var refItem = merchantRefDataList[i];
    if (refItem.refDataCategory.valueOf() === 'Merchant Type') {
        $scope.merchantTypes = refItem.refDataValues;
    } else if (refItem.refDataCategory.valueOf() === 'Merchant Category') {
        $scope.merchantCategories = refItem.refDataValues;
    } else if (refItem.refDataCategory.valueOf() === 'Merchant Business Type') {
        $scope.merchantBusinessTypes = refItem.refDataValues;
    } else if (refItem.refDataCategory.valueOf() === 'City') {
        $scope.cities = refItem.refDataValues;
    } else if (refItem.refDataCategory.valueOf() === 'Province') {
        $scope.provinces = refItem.refDataValues;
    } else if (refItem.refDataCategory.valueOf() === 'Country') {
        $scope.countries = refItem.refDataValues;
    }
}
```

The following code is used for getting the selected data into a form

```
$scope.merchantadd = {};
$scope.merchantadd.addressCity = '';
$scope.searchCity = "";
$scope.merchantadd.addressCity = $scope.merchantadd.addressCity.value;
```

The following html code is used to attempt searching for the values from the cities list:

```
<md-input-container>
    City
    <md-select required name="field" ng-model="merchantadd.addressCity">
        <md-select-header layout="column">
            <md-input-container>
                <input ng-model="searchCity" type="search" placeholder="Search..." class="mdSelectSearchBox md-text"/>
            </md-input-container>
        </md-select-header>
        <md-optgroup>
            <md-option ng-
                 {{city.value}}
            </md-option>
        </md-optgroup>
    </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```